# Using Integration To Find Impulse from Force-Time Graph

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, integration

Good day all,
This question is asking me to find impulse, J, for each cart by integrating force.

[image: Instructions for finding impulse]

I don't know how to pull the information from this force-time graph to set up the integral.

[image: Force-Time Graph]

Just to show how dumb I am, I attempted this for cart 2 (blue line):

[image: dumbass]

However, calculating impulse via change in momentum gives the value 8.0 kgm/s for the second cart. With the integrated value being way off from the change in momentum value. I have concluded I'm very wrong in setting up that integral (and very dumb).

How do I set up the integral with the graph information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite simple. The integral is the area under the curve. The only non-zero area under the curve is the diamond-shaped thing in the middle, which is a regular shape with a well-known area. If you drop a vertical from the top of the triangle to the x-axis, then you get two triangles whose area is simply

$A = \frac{base \times height}{2}$

And the total integral is the sum of the areas of the two triangles.